# Chromium Embedded Framework: Can I render into a canvas using DirectX?

Tags: chromium-embedded

i want to embed CEF into my DirectX application. Now I want to draw onto a Canvas element in the displayed html page using DirectX. This canvas may be obscured by other html elements above it so I cannot just take the absolute Canvas coordinates and render on it because then it would also render onto the elements on my canvas.

I see two possibilities to solve this:

- I can make CEF display my texture in the page, so CEF uses my bytebuffer as an image and updates that area frequently.
- I can get the area of the screen where the Canvas element is and that can actually be seen.

I could not find out if any of those two possibilities is possible in the docs or the sample application.

So my question is: Is this possible to achieve with CEF? And if yes how.

Answer (score 2):

The CEF feature what you are looking for named "off-screen rendering" and in this year it is renamed to "windowless rendering".

What are really available just now (in stable 1916 branch) - it is rendering to pixel buffer by software-only renderer. After this you can move your's pixel buffer to surface. Note that software renderer did not support gpu-only accelerated content. I.e. something like 3D CSS transforms and some animations will not work. But in general it is works fine.

You can test this mode by running `cefclient --off-screen-rendering-enabled`.

In CEF trunk branch 2042 - it is switched to new rendering codepath. And once issue https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1006 will be resolved - you can able to render directly into surface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I've seen off-screen rendering and I wanted to use it. The problem is: How can I find out where my canvas element is and what part of it is visible?

Comment: I'm not understand what it is canvas element. You need implement CefRenderHandler what exactly move image from internal pixel buffer to your's destination.

Comment: Do you mean render to a specific canvas inside the HTML tree node? If so, I am looking for the same thing :)

Comment: Of course browser renders whole page. If anyone want render just a piece of page - just create page only with required content. In embedded cases it is always available option.

Comment: Hi fddima, I think the question is about having full access/control of drawing over a dom-element/canvas from a native context - example: painting a pixel-buffer coming from a video source over a particular dom-element/canvas using CEF API. So, this wish is within the scope of usual windowed rendering. Not sure if off-screen-rendering can solve this

Comment: @Arjun windowless rendering solve this for whole viewport AND browser almost never render specific element to specific target. If you say about reverse painting then there is no room for discussion/questions - only CEF/Chromium patches can solve this. It should be clear for everyone, but no one usually do them. Of course some kind of overlay can be used - but in general case it is completely unreliable.