# real world user interfaces which are attractive and capable of high dynamic updates

Tags: user-interface

I promise I give my best to bring this question in a format matching the SO question format. Most of the questions of that kind seem to get closed.
Please consider not closing this question but giving hints how I could improve the question instead.

I am doing some research on the possibilities how I could implement a user interface which should meet two criteria (besides that it should work and be clearly to understand):

1. it should look attractive
2. it should be able to visualize high dynamic data (requires a lot of updates)

Well, the thing is I have a gaming background and a web background. In games the UI is rendered, like everything elsle, from the game loop which means you can visualize data changes with 30fps and up. This would meet criteria 2.

Use cases I can imagine for the high dynamic data updates would be:

- stock trading apps where the prize changes (I have to guess ~10 times per second)
- audio programs where the current position of the played audio track is synchronized in the display of the audio wave form
- dynamic changing [network graphs](https://nickpegg.com/2009/12/more_fun_with_graphs.html)
- real time visualization of procedural generated data (images, 3D models)

But developers outside of the gaming industry do not use game engines for their user interfaces.
I am trying to figure out how business software developers (in the real world) implement their user interfaces.

During the research I found those main streams:

1. business software libraries (user interfaces which get the job done for people who do a job)

   - like Windows Forms, Java Swing, Qt
   - they provide a lot of widgets, components (or whatever) and functionality
   - they are all grey in grey (though to some limited extend customizable)
   - they are very static (the layout) and react bad if you try to redraw the ui with 30fps
2. customer software libraries (user interfaces which attract people in their spare time)

   - those seem to be implemented more and more with HTML(5), CSS(3) and Javascript which utilize an embedded browser
   - they have an attractive look and feel
   - even the layout can be dynamic
   - examples would be the Steam and Spotify client (as I learned recently)
   - updating an HTML UI with 30fps seems not to be a good idea
3. the newcomers and the mixtures

   - meaning those who try to mix these already (JavaFX, Silverlight, dead Flash)
   - or they are new and limited to their devices (Android, IOS user interfaces)

There is always the option to write an UI system from scratch so it is tailored to the needs. But why reinvent the wheel because displaying dynamic data in an attractive way seems not be a new idea.

So the question: what is used in the real world?
Someone may provide names of applications displaying dynamic data so I can further research what they used.

I try to visualize dynamic data and avoid the (50 shades of grey style, although you can taint it black like VS 2015).
The programming language does not matter. It tends to become a desktop application (since a web application seems to be impossible so far).

Comment: You can't really expect an answer to such a question? All of the above. All of the above have already been used for such things, **including** HTML.

Comment: Why do you exclude web application? You would have to update your dynamic data - so one bottleneck is the connection from web to client. I don't see why an web application is not as good as a desktop application. The rendering itself could be faster when it is native but I think e.g. JavaScript is "adult" enough to cover your needs. There are plenty of frameworks, you may want to have a look at React?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, sure. I am always asking questions which I not expect to get answers for :-) I haven't seen released applications showing the real time process of image generation or procedural 3d model generation so far. If you have examples/links for any of them I really would be thankful.

Comment: @hering Well, I do not exclude HTML explicitly. I just haven't seen a way to to get the desired update frequency without using a canvas (which feels for me like writing a game engine ui again). Do you have any examples of real life applications (not demos of frameworks which show only the lesson 101 stuff but more the "par excellance" or "used to the maximum extend" part)?

Comment: How about one product that does all? Microsoft's PowerBI. Real-time web portal, embedded web dashboard *and* desktop WPF application. The same visualizations work for both. You can create your own custom visualizations like the [3D Globe Map](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visual-awesomeness-unlocked-the-globe-map/). Stock trading was one of the first markets to use "real"-time visualizations in the late 90s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, that helped and brought me a step forward. Haven't heard about PowerBI so far. Stock trading was the only thing I knew that it exists and could at least describe what I mean. There are also medical applications displaying real time scan results somehow but I don't even have a glue how they are named. But thats the direction what I am looking for. Thank you again.

Comment: You can also check the OSS [my-netdata.io](https://my-netdata.io/) project (repo [here](https://github.com/firehol/netdata)). Real-time performance monitoring for Linux servers. Just check the size of the scrollbar handle on the demo pages as an indicator of how much information is displayed on a single page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh pretty, I love it. They seem to use canvas for the the dynamic components and I guess some sort of webscockets. Haven't seen something like that in real life example. Just 101 demos. Big thx

Comment: And [Age of Ascent](https://www.ageofascent.com/) an HTML 3D space shooter. Not open beta yet, but the videos from their frequent play tests are pretty amazing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There are a couple of great 3D games/demos/tools out there. Using only a canvas always means loosing the utitlities of HTML (or other "framework") like tables, textfields, buttons or responsive layouts except there is a canvas ui library giving all that. No one so far implemented an HTML render engine for using a canvas. So HTML in a canvas inside HTML. just kidding.  The mixture used by my-netdata.io was perfectly fine.

Comment: One last question: how would you name this question or improve the way I asked it?

Comment: Interesting question I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535989/chromium-embedded-framework-can-i-render-into-a-canvas-using-directx